# How to get last ocurrence of a match in a string

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
{text"{id1}"},{text"{id2}"}
```

I'm using this regex:

```
{.*"{id2}"},?
```

But I'm getting the whole string and what I want to get is only this:

```
{text"{id2}"}
```

And if I use use id1 in the regex I want to get:

```
{text"{id1}"}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `{[^{}]*"{id2}"},?`

Comment: When you have *delimited* strings, when you need to match something between two chars, always prefer negated character classes to `.*` or `.*?`, unless you know what you are doing. `.` matches virtually every char, and it often leads to issues like this.

Comment: Okay I see it now, many thanks again!